# No puedo acceder a subcarpetas en Apache

Tags: apache

He instalado Apache y php manualmente, estoy usando estos directorios de trabajo

```
DocumentRoot "c:/Server/Apache/www/"
<Directory "c:/Server/Apache/www/">
```

Cuando pongo un archivo `index.php` en la carpeta `www`, puedo visualizar la página desde el navegador. El problema surge cuando creo una nueva carpeta. por ejemplo `practica_uno` y al poner `localhost/practica_uno` en el navegador me sale el siguiente error.

```
La página localhost no funciona
La página localhost no puede procesar esta solicitud ahora.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

Comment: windows server?

Answer (score 2):

intenta instalar todo el paquete ya sea usando [xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/es/download.html) o  [wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)

Answer (score 0):

Me pasaba lo mismo, instalaste el servidor usando la terminal, al parecer php no muestra los errores, ya que el comando viene desactivado por defecto, te sugiero abras la terminal y escribas:
"sudo gedit /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini"
 (sin las comillas y puedes cambiar "gedit" por "nano" o bien el editor que prefieras en tu distribución) buscas la linea "display_errors = Off" y la cambias a 
"display_errors = On" (esta en la linea 479... creo...)
guardas y sales.

[image: php.ini]

despues de eso escribes "sudo systemctl restart apache2" y luego vuelves a cargar la pagina. Todo esto suponiendo que estas usando Ubuntu(GNU/Linux), si estas usando windows, solo ve hacia donde se encuentra el directorio principal de php, y ahi edita php.ini, o bien presiona windows y teclea "php.ini", lo abres, editas y guardas, apagas apache y lo vuelves a encender.

eso soluciono mi problema, espero que pueda ayudarte en algo.

Nota:te va mostrar en que linea hubo el error de sintaxis, ahora solo ve y corrige...